# Function pointer is 0 after cast

Tags: c, operating-system, protected-mode

I am trying to develop my own OS. While setting up the IDT, I want to get address of the ISR0 function using &isr0 like this:

```
//The example function
void isr0() {
    volatile uint8_t* ptr1 = (uint8_t*)(0xB8000);
    ptr1[0] = 'A';
}
void main(){
    int ptr = (int)&isr0;
    volatile uint8_t* ptr1 = (uint8_t*)0xB8000;
    int offset2 = 40;
    int value = (int)ptr;
    ptr1[0 + offset2] = 48 + (value/100000) % 10;
    ptr1[2 + offset2] = 48 + (value/10000) % 10;
    ptr1[4 + offset2] = 48 + (value/1000) % 10;
    ptr1[6 + offset2] = 48 + (value/100) % 10;
    ptr1[8 + offset2] = 48 + (value/10) % 10;
    ptr1[10+ offset2] = 48 + (value/1) % 10;
    while(1);
    ...
}
```

And the output of this is 000000.

[image: Qemu window showing 000000]

On a normal Linux machine, it works with no problem showing me the memory location.

Also, I have noticed that when I try to make the function pointer and then call the function pointer, it does indeed work; however, when I try to get its value it just doesn't work. (&isr0 cannot be a problem then. It's the problem of somehow parsing it into int.)

Can anyone tell me why this happens, and how to fix it?

###### Steps to compile

```
i686-elf-gcc -nostdlib -O3 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -m32 -c kernel.c -o bin/stage4.bin
objcopy -O binary bin/stage4.bin bin/stage5.bin
```

- Bootloader: https://pastebin.com/vvDKG3EG
- Stage 2: https://pastebin.com/04k3FKGf

Compile those two using:

```
nasm stage1.asm -f bin -o bin/stage1.bin
```

And then just cat it all together:

```
cat bin/stage1.bin bin/stage2.bin bin/stage5.bin > bin/stage3.bin
qemu-system-x86_64 -fda bin/stage3.bin -vga vmware  -d guest_errors -m 64M >> bin/a 2>&1
```

Comment: Does your (emulated?) machine even have writable memory at 0xB8000 +40 through +50?

Comment: Yes it does (even on real hardware, in fact, tested that too) its set to index 40 cuz there is already something else being printed on +0

Comment: How big is a pointer and how big is an `int` in your OS? 32-bit? Both 4-bytes, okay, but if a pointer is 8-bytes and an `int` 4, that would explain your issue. Also, don't forget about *sign-extension* when using *signed* values where *unsigned* should be used.

Comment: Right, well there shouldnt be an overflow. The address of the function is around 0x7E80 soo that fits even to 16bit int. (i know i could've used the uint, but 2^16 < 2^31). I know the address preety good since when i am using absolute function pointer(0x7E71 to be exact, pointing to the stage2 code right before the C file, it works just fine)

Comment: Show us how you are building and linking your code, including linker scripts if applicable.  Sometimes this can happen if you built an image that needs relocation.

Comment: Added compilation steps.

Comment: I can't write an answer, but I think you should tell the linker the address of your code section, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508290/509868).

Comment: Well ye, but it should still return the offset from begining of the file, it shouldnt just return zero.

Comment: Unrelated, but stage2 assumes that the entry point of your kernel is its first byte.  This will only work if the `main` function happens to be the first thing in the file, and nothing in your build process ensures that: you could get some other function, or data.  That will be something else for your linker script to take care of: ensure the first thing in the kernel image is either the `main` function, or a stub that jumps to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i686-elf-gcc -nostdlib -O3 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -m32 -c kernel.c -o bin/stage4.bin 
objcopy -O binary bin/stage4.bin bin/stage5.bin
```

This won't work.  `gcc -c` produces a relocatable object file, which you've misleadingly named `stage4.bin` instead of `.o`.  It doesn't contain actual addresses of objects at the locations in memory where they need to be; rather, it puts in a placeholder (possibly 0), and has a separate relocation table to inform the linker of the name of the symbol whose address should go there.  But you didn't actually link the file; you just `objcopy`'d into binary, which simply discards the relocation table and leaves the memory location occupied by the 0 placeholder.

You have to actually run the linker on your object file to resolve all these references and build an executable, using an appropriate linker script.  See https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts for some examples.  Then you can `objcopy` to binary after that.

Comment: Well, if i do set my linker output format to binary, should i still objcopy it? And also, should i link the stage2 with the same linker and call it from there as main?

Comment: Btw, it seems to have fixed alot of other issues too! Thanks alot (e. g. function arguments)

Comment: @Stigl: I believe that using binary as your linker output format would also work instead of objcopy.  Doing objcopy from binary to binary would be pointless since it wouldn't do anything.  You don't need to link `stage2`, as it stands, because it's a self-contained assembly source with no external references.  In such a case, `nasm -f bin` is effectively an assembler and a linker rolled into one.  Besides, the GNU linker won't properly handle the 16-bit code in `stage2`.

Comment: Well, i think i somewhat solved it. I called the main function from the asm code (stage2) by linking them together and that seems to work.